# How to avoid copy/memory overhead when wrapping a stack allocated object?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a large blob object that is stack allocated. I need to put that in a wrapper object but I want to avoid a copy. Should I just use `std::move` with a move constructor? What would be the easiest way to prove that it works?

```
struct Blob {
    char blob[1024 * 1024]; // imagine something big here
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    Foo(T&& src) : data{src} {}
    T data;
};

int main() {
    Blob blob;
    Foo foo{std::move(blob)};  // do not copy
    // should not take twice the memory of a blob
}
```

Comment: Does `foo` need to outlive `blob`? If so, you're not going to be able to avoid moving/copying it at least once. If you're certain it won't outlive it, then you can safely just take a temporary reference.

Comment: Dynamically allocate the Blob, and pass pointers around.

Comment: `std::move` _allows_ move semantics on an object, if it is supported.  An array of `char`, however, **does not** have move semantics.  Why is it important to allocate this blob on the stack?

Comment: Why not store a simple reference to `blob`  or its relevant member?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yeah `foo` will outlive `blob` in my case.

Comment: unfortunately, I am getting passed with a blob and don't have much control over that. The char[] is just an illustration of something big... it's going to be some other structs in practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, `Blob` is plain old data.  The compiler is free to optimize the variable `Blob blob` out of existence.

It is also free to make a million copies of it for no reason whatsoever.  The standard does not constrain it.

There is an optimization called "static single assignment" that represents local object states as independent existence variables, which allows the compiler to get rid of a pile of nonsense copies or other state changes that don't matter.  Sufficiently complex code, or reference/pointer leaks outside of the scope of optimization, block it.

So, in practice, just don't block the compiler from optimizing `Blob blob`'s existence away.

That being said

```
Foo(T&& src) : data{src} {}
```

this should read

```
Foo(T&& src) : data{std::forward<T>(src)} {}
```

Also, you could do a

```
Foo<Blob&> foo(blob);
```

and have `Foo` store a reference to the `Blob` data.  This changes the "value semantics" of `Foo` in nasty ways however.

Note that your implicit deduction guide is equally crazy, in that if you pass an lvalue you'll get a `Foo` wrapping a reference, but if you pass an rvalue you get a `Foo` wrapping a value.

---

If you want a hard guarantee, C++ doesn't provide that.  C++ doesn't even guarantee that `Blob blob;` actually takes up space on the stack.

Going further, you can do this:

```
int main() {
  Foo foo{[&]{
    Blob blob;
    return blob;
  }()};
}
```

in this case, `Blob blob`'s existence is elided into the return value, which in turn is passed to `foo`, then the lifetime of the return value ends at th end of the full-expression.  Instead of a lambda, you can also use another function outside of `main`.

This makes it a bit easier for the compiler to work out that there is no point in a separate `Blob` object, but not be a huge amount.

If you want to make elision of the `Blob blob` directly into the `Foo data` be more guaranteed, add a `Foo` constructor that takes a `Blob` factory:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    template<class U>
    requires std::is_same_v< std::decay_t<U>, T >
    Foo(U&& src) : data{std::forward<U>(src)} {}
    template<class F>
    requires std::is_invocable_r_v< T, F&& >
    Foo(F&& f) : data(std::forward<F>(f)()) {}
    T data;
};
template<class T>
requires !std::is_invocable_v< T&& >
Foo(T&&)->Foo<std::decay_t<T>>;
template<class F>
requires std::is_invocable_v< F&& >
Foo(F&&)->Foo<std::decay_t<std::invoke_result_t<F&&>>>;

int main() {
  Foo foo{[&]{
    Blob blob;
    return blob;
  }};
}
```

which is probably going way, way too far.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Keep reference to original object in wrapper and use it through this.
2. Use NRVO to avoid copying.
   E.g.

```cpp
struct Blob {
    char blob[1024 * 1024]; // imagine something big here
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    template<typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>>
    Foo(): data(){}
    T data;
};

Foo<Blob> ProcessBlob(){
   Foo<Blob> value{};
   Blob& blob = value.data;
   // Use `blob` here
   return value; // NRVO would eliminate copying
}

void ProcessIn2Steps(){
   Foo<Blob> wrapped = ProcessBlob();
   // Use `wrapped` here
}
```

Also, if your really want to avoid copies, consider removing copy constructors of `Foo`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    template<typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>>
    Foo(): data(){}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(Foo&&) = delete;
    T data;
};
```

Comment: NRVO is a particular form of what C++ calls "elision".

Comment: I should have mentioned that `blob` has some useful data already filled in when I create the Foo wrapper. It seems that #2 suggestion here requires me to pass a reference of blob to some other process to fill in the data? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: @fatdragon Yes. You could read more about copy elision [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)